# ionic - BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am working ionic angular
while run this comment cordova build android --release
am getting this error
PS C:\Users\Nirali\Documents\nmhapp> cordova build android --release
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Nirali\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Nirali\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Nirali\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Nirali\Documents\nmhapp\platforms\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Nirali.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\7e15adv812akcxkuh6ist7or8).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 771ms
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\gradle.EXE -p C:\Users\Nirali\Documents\nmhapp\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Users\Nirali\Documents\nmhapp\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle
PS C:\Users\Nirali\Documents\nmhapp>

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to a snapshot of gradle 7.6, or wait for the 7.6 release
https://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-7.6-20221021231540+0000-bin.zip

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by opening my project in Android Studio, and it began building Gradle, then it recommended I upgrade Gradle. After the upgrade in Android Studio, I can now run my app.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows user:**

Go to C:\Users\arpan.gradle\caches and delete all the gradle cache.

then,

Go to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" there you will see jbr  and jre folder then copy the content of jbr and paste the content into jre folder.
ss:
[image]

and run flutter doctor again and run your App.